# How projective plane is used for projecting from the plane?

Tags: geometry, 3d, projective-geometry, infinity, projective-space

I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337820/what-is-the-relationship-between-projection-plane-and-projective-plane/4337850?noredirect=1#comment9047107_4337850) to understand difference between projection plane and projective plane. But below the @bubba's answer, the user
@Acccumulation comments this text which given below:

**The projection plane is where you're projecting onto a plane. The projective plane is where you're projecting from a plane, and filling in the points at infinity (those points exist in the projection despite not being in the original plane).**

My first question is what does mean second sentence of this comments? I mean when we do projection from 3D space to 2D onto projection plane, but what he mean, he means 3D space exists in projective plane?

When see the answer of @Lee Mosher he said homogenous coordinates are the points of $\mathbb R^3.$ But we see in many other answers homogenous coordinates are the points of projective plane $P^2.$ My second question is what is right? Homogenous coordinates belongs to $\mathbb R^3 or P^2?$

Comment: Let me answer the last question, to get you started. $\mathbb RP^2$ is a quotient space of $\mathbb R^3$. In particular, that means that for homogenous coordinates to belong to $\mathbb RP^2$, they must belong to $\mathbb R^3$ and also respect the quotient operation. (In other words, you can represent homogenous coordinates in $\mathbb R^3$, but the space has no knowledge of the fact that you are treating them as homogenous. It is more correct to say they belong to $\mathbb RP^2$).

Comment: For the first question, the projective plane $\mathbb RP^2$ is actually canonically embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ (as I said in the previous comment). So, you can view it as a projection of the plane onto 3D space, and some points added in to compactify the resulting projection. The projection plane is in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Don your second comments don't understand..

Comment: What part do you not understand...

Comment: @Don these two sentences "the projective plane RP2 is actually canonically embedded in R3  "."The projection plane is in the opposite direction"

Comment: The first one, you should understand from Lee Mosher's answer to your other question. The second is obvious: the projection plane sends 3D space to 2D space.

Comment: @Don please explain easily what does the mean quotient space RP^2 and what is quotient operation with one little example.

Comment: I won't. Not only did Lee do this in his answer, but it is literally one google search away as well.

Comment: I don't think "projection plane" is a standard term. That said, $\Bbb RP^2$ is the space of all lines in 3D through the origin. That means quotienting $\Bbb R^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$ by the equivalence relation $\vec{x}\sim\lambda\vec{x}$. Since every line goes through the unit sphere, this is equivalent to quotienting $S^2$ by the relation $\vec{x}\sim-\vec{x}$, i.e. identifying antipodal points. Equivalently, since every pair of antipodal points has a one point in a given hemisphere, we can quotient a disk by identifying antipodal boundary points.

Comment: This is all standard stuff. Google "projective plane RP^2" and you will find mountains of resources for you to choose from to help you understand. You can also look up stuff like quotient topology and equivalence relations. (Also I feel compelled to point out the statements "[RP^2 is] canonically embedded in R^3" and "RP^2 is a quotient space of R^3" are false statements.)